# Uploading large amount of data to Azure table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-table-storage, form-post

I'm trying to send a large amount of text in a form POST to azure table storage.
Each line of this text is going to be stored as one entity in the table. The problem I encountered now is that this operation exceeds the time limit.

> The operation has exceeded the default maximum time allowed for Windows Azure Table service operations

So I'm wondering is it possible to raise this limit, or how should I approach to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what you mean by "large amount of text".  What matters is how much data you are sending in a single shot into Azure; since you are breaking each line into its own entity, each entity can't be that large, right?

Here are a couple of ideas. Are you sending all the entities as a Batch operation? If so, the batch itself may be too large. You may want to send fewer entities at a time, or compress your data as a byte array for example. Or even better, save the data as blobs, and use the entity as a pointer to the URI of the blob.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear explanation. By large amount of text I mean I'm sending a single text that is maybe over 10000 + lines long. And because of that the time out will hit in and exception occurs.

Comment: I don't want to save it as blob, since I'm later going to use this data for some other services. So I rather store them as entities in the table if it is possible.

Comment: Ah - OK. Well... you may want to review some of the limitations of Azure Tables. Each entity in an Azure Table is limited to 1MB in size (that's across all the properties of an entity). So you may be sending more than 1MB for one entity, which explains why you are timing out. Check this link (see Property Limitations): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx

Comment: Sorry again if I made it unclear. Actually the entities are less than 1MB. The only problem is that I have a number of maybe 10000+ or more entities to insert. I have tried using batch saving, which is limited to 100 entities per save. Thus I made another approach to parallelise that work load into several threads. I'm not sure if it is the right way of doing it. It takes long time to process it though (around 1minute). So if there is a quicker solution I would like to hear it out.

Comment: Oh I see - thanks for the precision. Well, it seems you are hitting a throttling condition that prevents you from uploading all that data at once. The best you can do is implement a retry mechanism with backoff logic that will wait a little when you get timeout errors, then continue your upload process later. I built a backup/restore product that handles Azure Tables; that's what I had to do.  You have some other options too that could help: use multiple storage accounts to store the data (a form of sharding).